Modal dialog flow in rxjs and angular
I am new to rxjs pipelines in angular and I'm stuck in some simple (I suppose) flow. Here it is:

User wants to display form by clicking button
Some validation is happening -> if condition is met confirmation dialog is shown
If user accepts the form is shown

I want to pack it into one functional rxjs effect. Here it is working one:
export const showForm_effect = createEffect(
    (actions$ = inject(Actions), injector = inject(Injector), store = inject(Store)) => {
        return actions$.pipe(
            ofType(Actions.showForm),
            withLatestFrom(store.select(selectRegistryPage)),
            // pipe(
                exhaustMap(async ([action, registryPage]) => {
                    let userDecision: boolean  = true;
                    let showWarning = true;
                    if(registryPage.data.find(n => n.id == action.id)?.deviceInfo?.length == 0){
                        showWarning = false;
                        let modalService = injector.get(AppModalService);
                        userDecision = await modalService.confirm()
                    }
                    if(!userDecision){
                        return;
                    }
                    let modalService = injector.get(AppModalService);
                    const modalRef = modalService.openModalForm(FormComponent);
                    modalRef.component.id = action.id;
                    modalRef.component.showWarning = showWarning;
                    modalRef.result.catch((_) => { });
                    // return of(true);
                }),
                // map(userDecision => {
                //     if(!userDecision){
                //         return;
                //     }
                // let modalService = injector.get(AppModalService);
                // const modalRef = modalService.openModalForm(FormComponent);
                // modalRef.component.id = action.id;
                // modalRef.component.showWarning = showWarning;
                // modalRef.result.catch((_) => { });
                // }),
            // )
        )
    }, { functional: true, dispatch: false }
);

It works as I described the flow but I am not satisfied with this code and that is why:

I am not sure if using async in exhaustMap is a good practice
I think that showing form block shoud be in comment out map() statement
I was trying to meet these requirements but when I done this I had only userDecision flag available but I need rxjs action parameters and showWarning flag  too.

Or maybe that approach is not correct and I should break it into two effects?
I appreciate any help!
BR!

exhaustMap() should return an Observable, you can't just return;
